# Postgres EXPLAIN ANALYZE is super slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, explain

there is Postgres 9.6 on Redhat
I want to EXPLAIN ANALYZE slow query (quite complex one) and it takes too much time. My session with EXPLAIN ANALYZE consume 100% of one CPU and doesn't finish even after 24 hours.
How to analyze the issue if Postgres can't build an execution plan?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want to look at the execution plan, run `EXPLAIN` without `ANALYZE`.

`ANALYZE` will cause the query to be executed, which provides much more useful data, but takes as long as the query runs.